# UIViewController won't pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

so I have two view controllers setup like this in the interface builder:

[initial view] -- [signup view]. Initial view pushes to signup view via segue when a button is pressed. I have a back button on the signup view controller. When this is pressed I want to go back to the initial view controller. I am using this code:

```
- (IBAction)tapBack:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"back");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];       
}
```

the button is wired up correctly but nothing happens when I tap the button. Why is this? Does one of the UIVIewControllers have to be a UINavigationController to work or something? I am just using two UIViewController. Thanks

Comment: In your storybooard should be 3 controllers, one navigation controller as a root, attached as root the initial view and signup attached to initial view as push. BTW, do you see the navigation bar (with the view title)? I suspect that's the problem. Can I see a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: that was the problem, I didn't have a navigation controller set. Is it generally better practice to use navigation controllers? When popViewControllerAnimated is called is the UIVIewController destroyed or saved in the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If segue is modal then you cant pop back because it is modal view. To check, replace tabBack action method content with: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` if it pops back then segue is modal.

Comment: the problem was I wasn't using a UINavigationController. The code you posted works for my project that doesn't use a UINavigationController. When dismissViewController is called is the UIViewController destroyed or stored in the memory to be returned to later?

Comment: @Kex .They are Destroyed. You should use navigation controller. ALWAYS. try reading this: [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/ios-application-development-modal-navigation-view-controllers/) i hope that will explain difference.